# Android Jelly Bean offline Voice query

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Just a query

I made an voice command app for Android 2.3.x. 
This app takes voice commands and converts into text and perform the required action.

Now I have device having jelly bean. 
As jelly Bean introduces a new conversational text-to-speech voice in US English, available as both a network engine and an embedded engine via the TTS API.

If I have build this app with jelly bean and install in new device, will it work fine ??
will it uses offline voice-to-text automatically.

Please reply

Comment: You are mixing up text-to-speech and speech-to-text...

Comment: Just let me know app having voice to text apis build with 2.3.x will work or not in jelly bean device...if same workspace is build with 4.2 ???

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge android uses two different APIs for voice.

1.Voice typing i.e. key on keyboard

2.Voice Recognition i.e.Typing anywhere

Voice typing is enabled `offline` and voice recognition is not **(for 4.1 JellyBean)**.

This is why the key in the keyboard works offline, but nowhere else does.

For more info read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/add-voice-typing-to-your-ime.html).

Comment: I want to know whether my application for 2.3.x which converts voice to text.... will work in jelly bean or not ?